# Change authentication method when accessing Wso2 RemoteUserStoreManagerService

Tags: authentication, soap, wso2

Currently when accessing `/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl` soap endpoint of wso2 Identity server, the authentication method for this end point is Basic auth.

Is it possible to change this authentication method to something else, like some sort of token?Is this a possible option ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. This blog post has details.

http://soasecurity.org/2014/03/25/different-authentication-mechanism-for-wso2-carbon-management-console-and-admin-service-apis/